# How to use vee validate with textarea

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate

In my form i want to add a textarea field with vee validation.

Unfortunately, i cannot get the field to mentioned by yup schema.

```
import { Form, Field, ErrorMessage, useFieldError } from "vee-validate"
import { string } from "yup"
import * as yup from "yup"

const schema = yup.object({
  name: string().required("Mandatory field"),
  description: string().required("Mandatory field"),
})
```

This is my form field (**edit by last comment: i missed the "v-bind" but still not work**)

```
<Field name="description" v-slot="{ description }">
    <textarea v-bind="description" id="description" cols="30" rows="10" />
</Field>
```

The field is filled but the validation was not mentioned.

[image]

i followed an [example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-cwpemx?file=src%2FApp.vue), but it not work.

Comment: Your code is different from the example, you are missing at least `v-bind` which sounds very relevant :) Commenting because this is 90% guess

Comment: hey joel, thanks for your answer! yes, i missed the v-bind when i copy and paste because i tried a lot of different workarounds.. the v-bind not work.. the vee validation said the field is still empty.. instead i have insert a value

Answer (score 5):

You can add just prop `as` to `Field` component like this:

```
<Field as="textarea" name="description" id="description" cols="30" rows="10"/>
```

[Here](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/api/field/#rendering-simple-fields-with-as-prop) is API for `Field` component to rendering simple fields with ‘as’ prop

Answer (score 4):

Here's a [full working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-pk7usd?file=src%2FApp.vue):

```
<template>
  <Field v-slot="{ field, errors }" v-model="comment" name="comment" rules="required">
    <textarea v-bind="field" name="comment"/>
    <div v-if="errors[0]">{{errors[0]}}</div>
  </Field>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Field } from 'vee-validate';
import { defineRule } from 'vee-validate';
import { required } from '@vee-validate/rules';

export default {
  components: { Field },
  data() {
    return {
      comment:''
    }
  },
  created() {
    defineRule('required', required);
  }
};
</script>
```

Things you were missing:

- Rules ("required"), otherwise Vee Validate has nothing to do
- v-slot `errors` - get the errors so you can show them
- `v-model` on the `Field` (and a data element in your Vue component)

Comment: How can we solve the same problem using composition API with useField() ?

Comment: @martcube - sounds like a new question you could post :)